# Polymer 2.x Build Error - Multiple global declarations of class with identifier Polymer.Element

Tags: build, polymer, polymer-2.x

For every element that I have defined in a Polymer 2.x project I get the following warning:

> Multiple global declarations of class with identifier Polymer.Element

The build ultimately fails with a Promise rejection at `...\node_modules\polymer-build\lib\analyzer.js`

Are these components improperly defined?

How can I properly build the project?

My polymer.json file is

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "src/shop-app.html",
  "fragments": [
    "src/lazy-resources.html"
  ],
  "sources": [
    "src/**/*",
    "data/**/*",
    "images/**/*",
    "app.yaml",
    "bower.json",
    "manifest.json",
    "sw-precache-config.js",
    "Web.config"
  ],
  "extraDependencies": [
    "manifest.json",
    "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"
  ],
  "lint": {
    "rules": ["polymer-2-hybrid"]
  },
  "builds": [{
    "js": {"minify": true},
    "css": {"minify": true},
    "html": {"minify": true}
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that you load the same dependency from two different urls. For instance

```
myStuff/myApp.html
myOtherStuff/myApp.html
```

Comment: How can I tell what resource is being loaded multiple times? I tried building with the `--verbose` flag and I am still having trouble identifying the file...

Comment: Does this only happen during build or do you see similar error while looking at your projekt in the browser?

Comment: Maybe you can post your polymer json  + some more code?

Comment: I guess this is not Open Source? So i can have a look at it on github?

Comment: It only happens during build.  I was testing in IIS and not localhost.

Comment: Set "autoBasePath": true, in your polymer.json this will reset you base path.

Comment: Localhost showed a few errors in an if/else block that I was able to clear up and now I get a successful build.  However, I am still getting a `Multiple global declarations...` warning for each element that is defined in the project.

Comment: "Good" now run your page and in browser and check your network tab (f12) and check duplicates.

Comment: With `"autoBasePath": true` I still get the warnings.

Comment: Do I check for duplicates by running from the `build` folder or the `root`?

Comment: When running from the build folder: `GET http://localhost:8081/default/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: And `Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined`

Comment: I still get `GET http://localhost:8081/default/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js 404 (Not Found)` when adding it as an extra dependency in the `polymer.json` file.

Comment: Check first for duplicates from your uncompressed src.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same warning while building my Polymer 2 app. Probably because some of my elements import the same other elements and all of them extend `Polymer.Element`. I have checked all my elements for duplicate imports. Maybe some third party elements have duplicates, but my elements didn't.

So I added the warning to the ignore list in `polymer.json`:

```
{
  "lint": {
    "rules": [
      "polymer-2"
    ],
    "ignoreWarnings": ["multiple-global-declarations"]
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had same warning and it was gone after cleaning `bower_components` and `node_modules`.

Comment: What do you mean by cleaning?

Comment: @mat Sorry, I meant **clean install**. I basically deleted those two folders and installed all dependencies again.


rm -rf node_modules bower_components
npm install
bower install